# Why does getElementsByTagName shows error "is not a member of 'XDocument" in Visual Basic?

Tags: xml, vb.net, getelementsbytagname

I've been watching a bunch of videos about how to read XMLs with Visual Basic and I believe I'm following the correct steps, but I keep getting the error

> BC30456 getElementsByTagName is not a member of 'XDocument'

This is the code I have:

```vb
Dim document As New XDocument
Dim nodoLista As XmlNodeList
Dim nodo As XmlNode

document = XDocument.Load(path)
nodoLista = document.getElementsByTagName("Empresa")
```

[image: Code line]

I've looked for a replacement, maybe the code is old and was updated, but can't find ANYTHING, not even a similar error. I've also tried `SelectNodes`, but same error appears. Also I have the `imports system.xml` btw.

Also tried

```vb
nodoLista = document.Elements("Empresa")
```

but I get the error

[image: error]

Comment: `XDocument` is part of Linq to XML, not the DOM API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in your code seems like you wanted to code around `Xml.XmlDocument` instead of `Xdocument` as  `getElementsByTagName` is a Function of `Xml.XmlDocument` (*or its elements descendatnts*) which return a `XmlNodeList`
Here your code (modified):

```
Dim document As New Xml.XmlDocument 
Dim nodoLista As Xml.XmlNodeList
Dim nodo As XmlNode

document.Load(path)
nodoLista = document.GetElementsByTagName("Empresa")
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually want the Elements method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements

Here is an example:

```
Dim xml = "<root><Empresa>1</Empresa><Empresa>2</Empresa><Empresa>3</Empresa></root>"
Dim document = XDocument.Parse(xml)
Dim root = document.Element("root")
Dim empresas = root.Elements("Empresa")

For Each empresa In empresas
     Console.WriteLine("Empresa: {0}", empresa.Value)
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3THEAf